# Configure SonarQube to show one dashboard for multiple maven modules

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sonarqube

I am running SonarQube analysis with the Jenkins project and I have a project with a parent POM file that defines multiple modules.

Parent POM:

```
...
<groupId>com.abc</groupId>
<artifactId>appName</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>a</module>
    <module>b</module>
    <module>c</module>
</modules>
...
```

Child 'a' POM:

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>appName</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.abc.appName</groupId>
<artifactId>a</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>appName a module</name>
```

I would like for modules a b and c to show under the appName dashboard when they are scanned individually.

Is there a sonar or maven configuration that allows me to do this?

**Other items to take into account:**
1) currently the entire appname is scanned as one project with jenkins once a day.
2) each module is scanned upon checkin, therefore the keys exist and are the same, but when a single module is scanned by sonar, it shows its own dashboard and the dashboard under the appName -> component section is not updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SonarQube 3.7, to avoid such discrepancies, it is no longer possible to run analyses on the parent project and on each module. See http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4245.

Comment: I think that you should have provided a way to merge the data in this case since you can't run the parent if the child exists, you will lose all previous historical data.